# root cause and resolve an error returned R's 'lime' library's, 'explain' function

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I get this error when using the "explain" function from the "[lime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/index.html)" library on a h2o random forest.

```
Error in elnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, type.gaussian,  : 
  y is constant; gaussian glmnet fails at standardization step
```

I can't find documentation online, or help about this question online.  Can you help me root-cause and resolve it?

Here is my code:

```
explainer_h2o_rf  <- lime(x=big_df, 
                          model=fit_rf.hex, 
                          bin_continuous = FALSE,
                          use_density = T, 
                          quantile_bins = F)

# for(i in 1:25){
i <- c(1,2)
explanation_rf <- explain(x = x_lime[i,],
                          explainer = explainer_h2o_rf,
                          n_features = 15,
                          feature_select = "auto",
                          labels = "1")
```

Notes:

- I am predicting a binomial variable within the h2o model,
  'fit_rf.hex'.
- I worked through [this](http://uc-r.github.io/lime) and it worked, but my current approach does not
- The "lime" tag does not seem to apply to this lime library, but to something that is used for unit testing.
- The non-gaussian shouldn't be a problem, because (I think) I have set the flags that deal with non-gaussian (nearly all my data is non-Gaussian) data using kernel methods.

Here are sites/questions that didn't contain my answer:

- [Lasso error in glmnet NA/NaN/Inf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635508/lasso-error-in-glmnet-na-nan-inf)
- [glmnet training throws error on x,y dataframe arguments: am I using it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717201/glmnet-training-throws-error-on-x-y-dataframe-arguments-am-i-using-it-wrong)
- [Error - Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs)= etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179423/error-error-in-lognetx-is-sparse-ix-jx-y-weights-offset-alpha-nobs)
- [Error resulting in using cv.glmnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501108/error-resulting-in-using-cv-glmnet)

Comment: Please modify your code example to make it reproducible (it's missing data).

Comment: @ErinLeDell - It is proprietary, so that can't happen.  If you have a particular question about the nature of the data I might be able to help.

Comment: You don't need to post the proprietary data, but you do need to post an example that replicates the issue on a public dataset.  The first step of debugging is reproducing the error.

Comment: @ErinLeDell - The cheapest reproduction is one someone else already did, which happens with known/common errors, which I was hoping for.  I can work on trying to replicate this error in a different set of data, but I'm going to have to get lucky, and it is going to take time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error in elnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, type.gaussian,  :
>
> y is constant; gaussian glmnet fails at standardization step

Just reading the error, there seems to be a problem with your training data, or possibly some subset of the data that is used to train a `glmnet` model (`elnet()` is used inside the `glmnet()` function).

Specifically, the error indicates that the response column is constant and therefore cannot train an `glmnet` model -- training a `glmnet` model is a step inside the `model_permutations()` function, which itself is inside the `explain()` function.

You should check your response column to make sure that it's not constant.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error.

I changed `labels = "Yes"` to `labels = "Response"`, to match my target variable which resolved my issue.